# What are the steps to recover the OpenEBS Jiva volume from read-only?

Tags: storage, replicaset, openebs

I had a cluster situation where all the nodes with replica's went down, but now they are all back online and replicas are running. However, my volume mount at application is still complaining that the mount is read-only. What are the steps to recover?

Comment: Hi. This looks like a very broad question. Perhaps you can provide some more background information in your question.

Answer (score -1):

ISCSI is the connectivity link between application pod and OpenEBS controller pod. If this connection is broken for some reason, the filesystem on the application turns to ReadOnly (RO) mode and often the application pod can be found in CrashLoopBackOff state.

For the recovery steps, please visit the link below.
https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/readonlyvolumes.html